# MYSQL tied maxes

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hi I have a table that list Spanish classes start and finish time as well as date and teacher. 
I'm trying to write a MYSQL query that lists the that date each teacher has the most classes, the day which they are the busiest.
If there are days that tie I'd like to show both.

This is what I have so far but It only returns one date,even if there is a tie, I sense this is because I'm GROUPing on teacher at the end

```
SELECT teacher_no, date
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT(date)AS counted,teacher_no,date
   FROM Spanish
   GROUP BY teacher_no,date
) AS t
GROUP BY teacher_no
```

Comment: please use sqlfiddle.com to give us a sample of your structure and data.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44ac2/2

Comment: @ian we still need sample data. What output do you expect?

Comment: @jmilloy I liked a table with two columns, a row for each teacher_no and date their most, busy including tied days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  teacher_no, date, COUNT(date) AS counted
FROM    Spanish s
GROUP BY teacher_no, date
HAVING  COUNT(date) = (SELECT COUNT(date) AS counted
                       FROM Spanish
                       WHERE teacher_no = s.teacher_no
                       GROUP BY teacher_no, date
                       ORDER BY counted DESC
                       LIMIT 1
                      );
```

Comment: thanks but that produces the error -Unknown column 's.teacher_no' in 'where clause'

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. Is there a name for that kind of self reference i.e WHERE teacher_no = s.teacher_no

Comment: No problem.  I don't know if there is a name for that.  If there is, I don't know it.

Comment: @Ian - it's called a "correlated subquery".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you count the date in your inner query. I think it makes the more sense to count the start times. This gives you a table of the number of classes each teacher has on each date:

```
SELECT COUNT(start_time) AS classes, teacher_no, date
FROM Spanish
GROUP BY tearcher_no, date) AS t
```

For a particular teacher_no `X`, you can order by the number of classes to get the date with the most classes:

```
SELECT date
FROM (        
    SELECT COUNT(start_time) AS classes, date
    FROM Spanish
    GROUP BY date
    WHERE teacher_no = X) AS t
ORDER BY classes DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Finally, you can get the list of all teachers with something like

```
SELECT
    a.teacher_no,
    (SELECT date
     FROM
         (SELECT COUNT(b.start_time) AS classes, b.date
          FROM Spanish AS b
          GROUP BY b.date
          WHERE a.teacher_no = b.teacher_no) AS t
     ORDER BY classes DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS date
FROM Spanish AS a
GROUP BY a.teacher_no
```